# I don't want the app to run the MainActivity while I pressed home in SplashScreen just like WhatsApp

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I have put onPause in the SplashScreen activity to override the MainActivity but it won't work.
and I've searched the internet but still not find how to do it. it always start MainActivity even if I've pushed the home button

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    Thread splashScreenThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                super.run();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "showSplashScreen: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                Intent moveToHomeActivityIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(moveToHomeActivityIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    splashScreenThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Somewhat related: the way you create a SplashScreen is really bad. Please take your time to read https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154. After reading this your problem will be fixed + you will have a better Splash Screen + you will have happier users (I assume you care about your users)

Comment: please use below code just replace your thread and remove onPause method

Comment: @Zun your answer really helps me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this will working

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: well, I've implemented this, but it still moves to MainActivity despite I've already at android homescreen

Comment: okay so please check the HomeActivity maybe you have redirect the Home to MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your Manifest.xml and default your activity to SplashScreenActivity

**Change This**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity" />
```

**to This**

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

Comment: I've found the answer, just referenced to this https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the answer! It's so simple and easy to implement. just follow the instruction on this [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154)
Thanks @Zun for providing the reference